# Variable name from _multiple_ variables in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I'm using Opencart and I have a really useful plugin from an older version in php. I noticed that twig isn't that hard and I tried to convert the php code into twig. Simple ifs/for loops/echos were easy enough, but the original author uses dynamically created variable names.

I have seen examples using attribute and _context when the dynamic part comes from just one variable. But what happens when the variable name consists of 2, 3, or more variable parts?

This is an actual example (and there are many more like this)

```
${'var_' . $extension['name'] . '_' . $geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] . '_' . $customer_group['customer_group_id'] . '_order_total_sort_order'};
```

Is this something that can be achieved or is it a way of thinking totally incompatible with twig?

EDIT:
I understand how we use the value of a dynamically created variable. But is it possible to initialize it without knowing the various components in the first place? Or check if such a variable even exists? In my particular case the variables are created by user defined fields and then used freely, also passing through an if check.

`<select name="var_<?= $geo_zone['geo_zone_id']; ?>_<?= $group['group_id']; ?>_tax_class_id">
    <option value="0" <?php if(${'var_' . $geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] . '_' . $group['group_id'] . '_tax_class_id'} == 0){ echo 'selected'; } ?>><?= $text_none; ?></option>
</select>`

I honestly have no idea how this can be turned into twig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just concat them all?

```
{% set long_variable_name_here = 'foo' %}


{% set long = 'long' %}
{% set variable = 'variable' %}
{% set name = 'name' %}
{% set here = 'here' %}


{{ attribute(_context, long~'_'~variable~'_'~name~'_'~here) }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/53b43a)

---

```
{% set var_1_1_tax_class_id = 0 %}

<select name="var_{{ geo_zone['geo_zone_id'] | default(1) }}_{{ group['group_id']|default(1) }}_tax_class_id">
    <option value="0"{{ attribute(_context, 'var_'~geo_zone['geo_zone_id']|default(1)~'_'~group['group_id']|default(1)~'_tax_class_id') | default(-1) == 0 ? ' checked' }}>{{ text_none | default('text') }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Forgive my ignorance, but I press Run and the result is 'foo'. When I add `{{ long_variable_name_here }}` it also displays 'foo', as expected. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Well, you asked if it was possible to combine more than two dynamic variables to one. So yes, it is possible, even in twig?

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I mixed the variable name, with the variable value. Silly me! Just a follow up question. What happens when, let's say the name changes, so then we need `long_variable_anotherName_here`? I tried it and it says "key does not exist". Because that's the point of having a dynamically created variable name, you can't know beforehand the actual name.

Comment: Looking at the corresponding html/php file, I guess the alternate variable names are declared first. E.g. through user input (`<input ... value=long_variable_anotherName_here>`). There's an order in things, declaration precedes use (obviously!), so then we can use them in various mix & match ways.

Comment: Thanks so much @DarkBee. Through your example (and the compiled php template) I've also really understood how the mechanics of attribute and _context work. I was racking by brain these past couple of days trying to understand something not that well documented. :)

Comment: Sorry for my incessant comments, but I'm trying to wrap my head around the whole concept and I've hit a snag. I've updated the question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: From your latest example, I figure there has to be some initial (static) declaration. Thanks @DarkBee, I'll give it a try!