# Twig Syntax - How to get value from nested dynamic key

Tags: php, twig, opencart

Recently I have been working on opencart 3 project where I came across a requirement which needs nested dynamic value i.e.

```
{{ 'module_default_{{ geo_zone.geo_zone_id }}_{{ customer_group.customer_group_id }}_flat' }}
```

`geo_zone` is a dynamic key which gives certain value so does the `customer_group_id`.

Based on the above dynamic values we get a key to say `module_default_0_1_flat` now this becomes a key of my plugin. So using the above key we can get a certain value.

```
{{ module_default_0_1_flat }}
```

I know we can define the key in a variable but there's a huge number of variables I have to define if that approach is taken.

Hence want a simpler approach which can get me values from nested dynamic keys.

## Here are some known facts

Based on the duplicate issue raised, I'm well aware of the fact on how to access the dynamic variable. If I had to set variables I would have done it instead of wasting much time.

Well, I want to know, is how you can achieve this problem statement without creating multiple variables which is unnecessary.

Hence, I'm not looking for a solution like this

```
{% set long = 'long' %}
{% set variable = 'variable' %}
{% set name = 'name' %}
{% set here = 'here' %}
```

Rather looking for an efficient way to resolve the conflicts.

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - How to access dynamic variable names in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/symfony2-how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable name from \_multiple\_ variables in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803112/variable-name-from-multiple-variables-in-twig)

Comment: Did you guys tried to understand or bothered reading my query that you marking it as duplicate?

Comment: You do realize the snippet u copied makes no sense at all because I just used that as an example? Rather have a look at my 2nd snippet in the linked answer

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted a more "easier" solution, then the only thing I can suggest is adding a function to `twig` that does the combine for u

```
<?php
    $twig->addFunction(Twig_SimpleFunction('dynamic_value', ($context, ...$keys) {
        return isset($context[implode('_', $keys)]) ? $context[implode('_', $keys)] : null;
    }, ['needs_context' => true, ]);
```

Then U could something like this inside `twig`

```
{{ dynamic_value('module_default', geo_zone.geo_zone_id, customer_group.customer_group_id, 'flat') }}
```